# Elements outside of scroll area

Tags: html, css

I'm making a messaging app in Electron. I'm using backdrop-filter to blur the messages as they scroll past the title bar, so I need the messages to pass behind the title bar, rather than being contained inside their own div in the middle of the screen.

When the page is not scrolled, the messages behave as expected. However, at the bottom of the page, the messages are cut off by the bottom bar for entering messages.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chat.css" />
    <script src="js/chatWindow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <span class="name">Room Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="messageBar">
        <input id="messageBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter a message..." />
        <div class="sendBtn">Send</div>
    </div>
    <div class="messageList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto Light";
    font-style: "normal";
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "Roboto Light";
    padding: 45px 0px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(56, 92, 254, 0.75);

    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
.header span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.messageBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 45px);
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(57, 93, 255, 0.75);

    padding: 0px;

    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}

#messageBox {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

    font-size: 1em;

    margin: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
#messageBox::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: dimgray;
}

.sendBtn {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    line-height: 45px;

    transition: 0.2s;
}
.sendBtn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.messageList {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.message {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.message.mine {
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaVwVq) for an example of what's happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried setting a bottom margin to your `.message:last-child` ?

Comment: if you used position for header and footer, you can use it too for the middle box : `.messageList {
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:45px;
  bottom:45px;
  overflow:auto;
}` or use another layout method involving display instead position

Comment: t3__rry Fixed it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code may this help you.

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    var messageList = document.querySelector(".messageList");
    var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox")
    var sendBtn = document.querySelector(".sendBtn");

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var content = "Message body: " + i + "\nThe quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        createMessageBubble(content, Math.random() > 0.5);
    }

    sendBtn.onclick = function() {
        var message = messageBox.value;
        messageBox.value = "";
        if(!message || message.length <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        createMessageBubble(message, true);
        // TODO: actually send the message
    };

    function createMessageBubble(content, isUser) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.classList.add("message");
        if(isUser) {
            el.classList.add("mine");
        }
        el.innerText = content;
        messageList.appendChild(el);
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100%";
    div.style.height = "45px";
    div.style.float = "left";
    messageList.parentNode.appendChild(div);
});
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't really work. I ended up adding a margin to the :last-child of each message. Thanks anyway :)